# AutoLISP - Change Layers Automatically

Tags: lisp, autocad, autocad-plugin, autolisp

I want to make a simple AutoLISP routine where I draw lines in layer `"0"` and afterwards change back to the original layer.

With the code below, I can draw a line but it will stay in the current layer. If I let out the last code line, I draw the line in layer `"0"` but afterwards there is no change back to the original layer.

```
(defun c:testfunction (/ OLD)
  (setq OLD (getvar 'clayer))
  (setvar 'clayer "0")
  (command "line")
  (setvar 'clayer OLD)
)
```

**Concept of the Code**

I first store the current layer in the `OLD` variable, then I change the layer to `"0"`. After the `LINE` command I change back to the `OLD` layer.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Pausing for Input

Since the AutoCAD [`LINE`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-E8C1190C-A26C-484C-ADDD-DDF81666F69F) command can issue an arbitrary number of prompts to the user (depending on the number of lines they wish to draw), you'll need to include a loop within the code to allow for an arbitrary number of user inputs, before resetting the current layer.

Your current code will evaluate the expression `(setvar 'clayer OLD)` *before* the user has supplied the first line point, as there is no pause for user input.

To [pause for user input](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-9D921CDD-89A3-44AB-865A-00F8986611F2) in an AutoCAD command invoked from an AutoLISP program or toolbar macro, you use the backslash `\`.

However, since the backslash is an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) in AutoLISP, you'll need to prefix it with another backslash in order to output a *literal* backslash to the command, e.g. `\\`.

Aside: the [`pause`](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2013/ENU/index.html?url=files/GUID-93E25253-F42A-4E85-84AD-4DCA66DB48A6.htm,topicNumber=d30e578088) symbol also evaluates to a backslash, but since this symbol is not protected and may be redefined, I would always recommend using a literal backslash.

And so we might use:

```
(command "line" "\\")
```

However, this only pauses for a single input, and the AutoCAD [`LINE`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-E8C1190C-A26C-484C-ADDD-DDF81666F69F) command will accept an arbitrary number of inputs, and so we need a way to construct a loop and determine when the user has finished with the command.

For this, we can make use of the [`CMDACTIVE`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-18B2E090-6C94-4C24-A70A-F2D6BDD5569C) system variable, which is a bit-coded system variable indicating the current command state - a bit code of `1` indicates that a command is active.

To test whether bit code `1` is set, we can use the AutoLISP [`logand`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-4E042C63-8BD7-4FED-B9E1-B5CE12D18273) function, which returns the bitwise [`AND`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) of two supplied integers, e.g.:

```
(logand 1 3) => 1

(logand 1 2) => 0
```

Combining this with the [`CMDACTIVE`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-18B2E090-6C94-4C24-A70A-F2D6BDD5569C) system variable we have:

```
(logand 1 (getvar 'cmdactive))
```

Which will return `1` if a command is active, else `0` otherwise.

Hence the test expression for our loop can be:

```
(= 1 (logand 1 (getvar 'cmdactive)))
```

And now it just remains to construct the loop itself - for this, we can use the AutoLISP [`while`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-E7C900DB-8B66-4109-BEF6-B0A18E8CF6B6) function:

```
(while (= 1 (logand 1 (getvar 'cmdactive)))
    (command "\\")
)
```

The above will continue to pause for user input whilst a command is active.

### Putting it all Together

Putting everything together, we have:

```
(defun c:testfunction ( / old )
    (setq old (getvar 'clayer))
    (setvar 'clayer "0")
    (command "line")
    (while (= 1 (logand 1 (getvar 'cmdactive)))
        (command "\\")
    )
    (setvar 'clayer old)
)
```

However, there are few other enhancements that we can make here...

### Additional Enhancements

- We can add a [`(princ)`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-7DDA298B-A97C-49C9-94BA-46C77B50AE99) expression to the end of the function definition to suppress the value returned by the last evaluated expression. As written, the current function will return the value returned by the [`setvar`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-B1CE1BFB-2448-47F1-95EC-10E9509F01FA) function, which will be the name of the original layer.

  We can use [`(princ)`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-7DDA298B-A97C-49C9-94BA-46C77B50AE99) at the end of the definition to instead return a null symbol to the command line, and hence cleanly exit the program:

  ```
  (defun c:testfunction ( / old )
      (setq old (getvar 'clayer))
      (setvar 'clayer "0")
      (command "line")
      (while (= 1 (logand 1 (getvar 'cmdactive)))
          (command "\\")
      )
      (setvar 'clayer old)
      (princ)
  )
  ```
- We can prefix the invocation of the AutoCAD [`LINE`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-E8C1190C-A26C-484C-ADDD-DDF81666F69F) command with an underscore to account for localised versions of AutoCAD (in which the [`LINE`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-E8C1190C-A26C-484C-ADDD-DDF81666F69F) command may be called something else):

  ```
  (command "_line")
  ```

  The use of an underscore command prefix ensures that we are invoking the non-localised English [`LINE`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-E8C1190C-A26C-484C-ADDD-DDF81666F69F) command.
- We can prefix the invocation of the AutoCAD [`LINE`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-E8C1190C-A26C-484C-ADDD-DDF81666F69F) command with a period to account for possible redefined versions of the AutoCAD [`LINE`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-E8C1190C-A26C-484C-ADDD-DDF81666F69F) command:

  ```
  (command "_.line")
  ```

  Since it is possible to redefine AutoCAD commands, the use of a period command prefix ensures that we are invoking the non-redefined standard [`LINE`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-E8C1190C-A26C-484C-ADDD-DDF81666F69F) command.
- We can add a local error handler to automatically reset the current layer to the original layer if the user presses <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit the program:

  ```
  (defun c:testfunction ( / *error* old )

      (defun *error* ( msg )
          (if old (setvar 'clayer old))
          (if (not (wcmatch (strcase msg t) "*break,*cancel*,*exit*"))
              (princ (strcat "\nError: " msg))
          )
          (princ)
      )

      (setq old (getvar 'clayer))
      (setvar 'clayer "0")
      (command "_.line")
      (while (= 1 (logand 1 (getvar 'cmdactive)))
          (command "\\")
      )
      (setvar 'clayer old)
      (princ)
  )
  ```

  For more information on how the local error handler operates, you may wish to refer to my AutoLISP tutorial on [Error Handling](http://lee-mac.com/errorhandling.html).
- We could also test to ensure that layer `0` is not frozen before attempting to set it as the current layer, but this goes beyond the scope of this beginner's program.

### Extending the Idea

With the above approach we have defined our own custom function to store the current layer, set a new current layer, invoke the `LINE` command, and then reset the original current layer.

But this means that the user must remember to invoke our custom version of the `LINE` command, rather than the standard `LINE` command.

What if there was a way to *automatically* set & reset the current layer when invoking *standard* AutoCAD commands? Well, through the use of Visual LISP Reactors, there is.

In my open-source [Layer Director](http://lee-mac.com/layerdirector.html) application, I demonstrate how you can use Command Reactors & LISP Reactors to automatically create, set, and reset the current layer when standard AutoCAD commands are invoked:

[image]